# Get value of xml attribute when desearlizing xml to c#

Tags: c#, xml

What I'm trying to do is get the attribute values from the type attribute on the ID tag in the Included_By_Organization collection in the below xml. I can get the values just fine but the attribute comes back null.

Included by organization object example:

Type: null <-- I need this to be Organization_Reference_ID
Value: RU7860

XML

```
<wd:Included_by_Organizations wd:Descriptor="RU7860 Europe Forwarding Overhead">
        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b8129574800601751d8538accb023f35</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">RU7860</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Custom_Organization_Reference_ID">RU7860</wd:ID>
</wd:Included_by_Organizations>
```

Class for xml array

```
        [XmlAttribute("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public IncludedByOrganization()
        {
        }
```

Class for getting xml values

```
    [XmlElement("Reference_ID")]
    public string CostCenterId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Included_by_Organizations")]
    [XmlArrayItem("ID")]
    public IncludedByOrganization[] IncludedByOrganization { get; set; }
```

Method to desarlize

```
        ReportData reportDataList = new ReportData();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ReportData));

        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath))
        {
            ReportData reportData = (ReportData)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reportDataList = reportData;
        }

        return reportDataList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example I've created another one and managed to read the `type`.

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot()]
public class XML
{
    [XmlArray("Included_by_Organizations")]
    [XmlArrayItem("ID")]
    public IncludedByOrganization[] IncludedByOrganization { get; set; }
}
```

Notice the `[Serialization, XmlRoot()]` attirbutes.

```
[Serializable]
public class IncludedByOrganization
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public IncludedByOrganization()
    {
    }
}
```

Also added `[Serialization]` attribute.

Text example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XML>
    <Included_by_Organizations Descriptor="RU7860 Europe Forwarding Overhead">
        <ID type="WID">b8129574800601751d8538accb023f35</ID>
        <ID type="Organization_Reference_ID">RU7860</ID>
        <ID type="Custom_Organization_Reference_ID">RU7860</ID>
    </Included_by_Organizations>
</XML>
```

The example is stored in `string xml`.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XML));
var reader = new StringReader(xml);
var deserialized = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

The result:

[image]